# DataException could not execute query

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

Hi I'm getting DataException while executing the following query :

```
 GET_USERLIST_BY_GROUP1 =   "   SELECT usr.user_id,
       usr.login_name
FROM user_info usr
WHERE usr.user_id IN
    (SELECT g.user_id
     FROM group_privilege_details g
     WHERE g.group_id IN
         (SELECT gp.group_id
          FROM group_privilege_details gp,
               user_info u
          WHERE u.user_id=gp.user_id
            AND u.login_name=?)
     GROUP BY g.user_id HAVING count(g.group_id) =
       (SELECT count(g.group_id)
        FROM group_privilege_details gr,
             user_info us
        WHERE us.user_id=gr.user_id
          AND us.login_name=?))
  AND usr.login_name!=?"
```

Please find the piece of hibernate code :

```
qry = hiberSession.createSQLQuery(GET_USERLIST_BY_GROUP1);
qry.setParameter(0, argUsername);
qry.setParameter(1, argUsername);
qry.setParameter(2, argUsername);
lstUsernamebyGroup = qry.list();
```

Please find my exception :

```
2011-10-22 12:42:55,352 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-10.128.15.228-8080-5) org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute query

2011-10-22 12:42:55,352 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-10.128.15.228-8080-5)  at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:77)

2011-10-22 12:42:55,352 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-10.128.15.228-8080-5)  at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)

2011-10-22 12:42:55,353 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-10.128.15.228-8080-5)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2223)

2011-10-22 12:42:55,353 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-10.128.15.228-8080-5)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)

2011-10-22 12:42:55,353 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-10.128.15.228-8080-5)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)

2011-10-22 12:42:55,354 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-10.128.15.228-8080-5)  at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:378)

2011-10-22 12:42:55,354 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-10.128.15.228-8080-5)  at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:338)

2011-10-22 12:42:55,354 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-10.128.15.228-8080-5)  at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:172)

2011-10-22 12:42:55,355 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-10.128.15.228-8080-5)  at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1121)

2011-10-22 12:42:55,355 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-10.128.15.228-8080-5)  at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:79)
```

Comment: You're missing the message from the exception, which will no doubt explain what's wrong...

Comment: Is there no nested exception? I'd expect there to be...

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I see slightly out of place with your SQL is the fact that you use "!=" for not equal. The official not equal SQL operator is "<>". Postgres supports "!=" as well, but maybe Hibernate has trouble with that.